# VBS: конвертирование .xls в книгу формата .xlsx

Tags: excel, vbscript

Возникла необходимость написать *VB*-скрипт, который конвертирует книгу формата *.xls* в книгу формата *.xlsx*.

Код собрал из нескольких источников, но он не работает.

Код скрипта:

```
Sub ConvertToXlsx()  
    Dim strPath 
    Dim strFile
    Dim wbk

    strPath = "<путь_к_файлу>"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "20170619-1708-results-CustomObject3_new.xls")

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFile)
    wbk.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & strFile & "x",_
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False    
End Sub
```

В книге есть три листа: *Сводка*, *Отклонено* и *Сведения*. Есть ли возможность сохранить в новой книге *.xlsx* все три страницы сразу?

Сейчас при запуске скрипта (запускаю через батник) вылетает вот такая ошибка:

[image: Error]

Подскажите, что я делаю не так и, если можно, какую-нибудь литературу по *VBS*.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить задачу. Привожу код ниже.

ВНИМАНИЕ! Для работы скрипта у Вас должен быть установлен MS Excel.
Данный код конвертирует файл формата .xls в формат .xlsx.

```
Sub ConvertToXlsx()

        'Dim strPath 
        Dim strFile
        Dim wbk
        Dim app

        Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        app.Visible = False
        app.DisplayAlerts = False

        strFile = "<путь_к_файлу_xls>"

        Set wbk = app.Workbooks.Open(strFile)
        wbk.SaveAs "путь_к_файлу_xlsx", 51
        'FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        wbk.Close True

        app.Quit
        Set wbk = Nothing    
        Set app = Nothing
    End Sub

    ConvertToXlsx()
```